# Specifying Typescript Type Definition Versions

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript, tsd

I am a new to TypeScript and a bit confused. If my version of TypeScript is 1.0.1 (say I'm stuck on VS2012), how do I use tsd to find type definitions for a library that given I require tsc 1.0.1.

Without version information, I will often get type definitions for tsc1.4.

I figure there must be a way to do this in tsd, but I have not been able to figure it out.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to download TypeScript type definitions for an older version of TypeScript with `tsd`, you may do the following.

If you look inside `tsd.json` you will see the key `"ref"`, which is set to `"master"`.

```
{
  "version": "v4",
  "repo": "borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped",
  "ref": "master",
  ...
}
```

This refers to the `master` branch of [`borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped`](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master).

There are other branches of [`borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped`](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master) such as `1.0.1` which target previous releases of TypeScript.

Simply modify `tsd.json` to point to another branch, and it will retrieve type definitions specific to that version of TypeScript.

```
{
  "version": "v4",
  "repo": "borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped",
  "ref": "1.0.1",
  ...
}
```

After you have done this, you can install a type definition with `--save` and inspect the commit hash in `tsd.son` to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

> how do I use tsd to find type definitions for a library that given I require tsc 1.0.1

You can't *easily*. You need to run `tsd install somedefinitionyoucareabout -soa` and then change the git sha saved in `tsd.json` to some thing that is from the `1.x` branch: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/1.0.1

That said *you really should consider updating to TypeScript latest*.

Comment: Thanks! Shortly after I asked this question I took a look at `tsd.json` and changed the branch from `master` to `1.0.1`.

At first glance, it _seems_ to have properly pulled down TypeScript 1.0.1 compatible definitions. Do you have any experience with this?

Comment: And in fact better :)